# не работает отображение программы по размеру экрана

Tags: qt

пытаюсь сделать программу которая будет смотреть (аппаратно) размер экрана монитора и будет выводить на экран, форму(ui) на половину экрана.

Создал пустой проект с ui  и решил попробовать разные варианты. в редакторе ui, sizePolicy горизонтальная: Preferred вертикальная: Preferred .

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#define PERCENT_OF_SCREEN (25 / 100)

#include <QRect>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

   // !формирование размера то монитора
   QRect r = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
   this->resize(r.width() * PERCENT_OF_SCREEN, r.height() * PERCENT_OF_SCREEN);
// --- не сработало, но ошибок не выводит
  // ---  №2
  QRect obl = QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry();
  qDebug() << obl.width();
  this->resize(obl.width()/2,obl.height()/2);
  this->move((QApplication::desktop()-this->width())/2,(QApplication::desktop()-this->height())/2);
 // --- ошибка 2352
 // --- №3
 QRect QScreenRect = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry(1);
 this->resize(QScreenRect.width()/2,QScreenRect.height()/2);
 // ---не сработало, но ошибок не выводит
 // --- №4       
  QRect QScreenRect = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry(1);
  int x = QScreenRect.width()/3;
  qDebug() << "x:" << x;
  int y = QScreenRect.height()/3;
  qDebug() << "y:" << y;
  this->resize(x, y);
  // --- не сработало, но ошибок не выводит
  // --- №5
   QRect ecran = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry();
   int x1 = ecran.width()/3;
   qDebug() << "x1:" << x1;
   int y1 = ecran.height()/3;
   qDebug() << "y1:" << y1;
   this->setGeometry(35,35,x1,y1);
  // --- меняет расположение формы но не меняет размер формы
  // --- №6
   this->setGeometry(30,30,640,344);
   this->resize(640,344);
   //this->resizeEvent(x1,y1); // ошибка 2660
   // --- тут я уже потерял всякую надежду и попробовал 
   // жестко задать но размер формы.размер формы не поменялся
    // --- №7
   this->resize((QApplication::desktop()->width())/2,(QApplication::desktop()->height())/2 );
   // --- не сработало, но ошибок не выводит
ui->setupUi(this);
```

}

Пробовал по одному варианту все остальные блокировал.

Так и не понял что я делаю не так, работаю в Qt4.8.4

п.с. Раньше создавал программы в qt но размер форм задавал руками из за чего на разных компьютерах, особенно если экран не большой выходило не очень(форма выходила за экран компютера)

**!!! Я допустил ошибку ui->setupUi(this); надо было вставить в начало всех вариантов, а не в конце ибо если в конце то он(qt) размер формы берет из редактора !!!**

пример:

```
  ui->setupUi(this);
  QRect QScreenRect = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry(1);
  this->resize(QScreenRect.width()/2,QScreenRect.height()/2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы делаете манипуляции с размером формы в конструкторе до вызова `setupUi`, который переинициализирует размеры на те, что используются по умолчанию.

Вот такой код в конструкторе у меня работает корректно:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
QRect r = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
this->resize(r.width() * 0.25, r.height() * 0.25);
```

З.Ы. Обратите внимание, что ваше `#define PERCENT_OF_SCREEN (25 / 100)` рассчитывается как целое и равняется нулю

Answer (score 0):

Дам ответ в связи с тем что слегка что то изменилось в куте(в куте 6.2) , нужно воспользоваться другой командой :

```
QRect size = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->geometry();
this->resize(size.width() * 0.25, size.height() * 0.25);
```